# How are elements stored in containers in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, data-structures, containers

How are elements stored in containers in .Net?
For example, a C++ vector stores in sequential order, while List doesn't.
How are they implemented for .Net containers (Array, ArrayList, ...)?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487202/memory-layout-of-a-net-array

Comment: Almost, but there is only for array, but I need for all containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the element. But a C++ `Vector` is equivalent to a C# `List`, and a C++ `List<T>` is equivalent to a C# LinkedList

The C# `ArrayList` is pretty much, a C# `List<object>`

Wikipedia lists [many data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures), and I suggest you have a look there, to see how the different ones are implemented.

So:

```
C++        C#                      How
Vector     ArrayList / List        Array (sequential)
List       LinkedList              Linked List (non-sequential, i.e. linked)
```

Answer (score 1):

It varies by container. Because the implementation is proprietary, there are no public specs mandating what the underlying data structure *must* be.

If you're interested in taking the time, I've used the following tools before to understand how MS implemented this class or that:

- Debugging with the Microsoft .NET Framework debugging symbols.
- Inspecting assemblies with Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

In .net, containers (even arrays) handle all access to them.  You don't use pointers to work with them (except in extremely rare cases you probably won't ever get into), so it often doesn't matter how they store info.  In many cases, it's not even specified how things work behind the scenes, so the implementation can be changed to something "better" without breaking stuff that relies on those details for some stupid reason.

Last i heard, though, arrays store their entries sequentially -- with the caveat that for reference-type objects (everything that's not a struct), "entries" are the references as opposed to the objects themselves.  The data could be anywhere in memory.  Think of it more like an array of references than an array of objects.

ArrayLists, being based on arrays, should store their stuff the same way.