# What is at the beginning of an array object in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, memory, memory-address

As far as I know, object variables point to/reference the beginning of their respective object addresses.

```
class Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
```

In the above code, `foo` would point to an instance of `Foo` created by using `new` operator, and if the address of that instance was at 0x0010, the address of field `a` (or maybe `b`) would also be 0x0010. Similarly, if I created an array of integers and the array object was created at 0x0020, the element at index 0 would share the same address (the indexes are just offsets, right?). However, after reading this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects#S7), it seems that, at least in C#, 4 bytes are allocated for TypeHandle at the beginning of every object. If true, then does the first element of every array really start at object address + 4?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487202/memory-layout-of-a-net-array note that you are asking about the non-guaranteed internals of a particular CLR implementation

Comment: Ultimately, this is implementation specific. .NET does not require a specific physical memory layout. It's possible that different versions of .NET and other current or future implementations use a different strategy to store arrays.

Comment: Indeed, it's nice to know how it works under the hood, but you should never *rely* on it. A conforming implementation of .NET might hold arrays on the stack, it might have a completely different layout, it might even implement the whole thing on punch cards, or pen and paper. The array might not even exist at all (having been optimized away)

Comment: You would want to specify `[StructLayout]` attribute to have a defined layout in a struct.

Comment: @pm100 Thanks for sharing that link! I got really valuable information from there, and it seems that the first element of an array does get stored 4 bytes from the beginning of the array instance to account for the overhead

Comment: @EricJ. Understood. I had been under the impression that the index of an array was a hard value indicating the offset, but it seems that it is implementation specific and that array[0] does not necessarily live at the beginning of the array instance memory

Comment: @JaeYi that link shows offset 8 to  first element . 4 bytes method table pointer, 4 bytes array length

Comment: @pm100 I misread that--thanks for pointing that out for me!

Comment: @Charlieface 'pen and paper' I think you have cracked why my latest c# app is so slow

Comment: @pm100 You missed the fact that my punch cards are situated on the other side of the globe and all communication is by [the IPoAC protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers), and given the latency involved and TCP's inherent latency-bound issues, that can also cause slowness